# change key names of JSON using array

Tags: javascript, json

Say I have some JSON data like this:

```
blah = [
{"Species":"setosa","Sepal.Length":5.1,"Sepal.Width":3.5},{"Species":"setosa","Sepal.Length":4.9,"Sepal.Width":3}
]
```

In my code, I won't necessarily know the key names of the JSON. Therefore, I can grab the keys like this (I do know that all elements of the array are identical in their keys):

```
mynames = Object.keys(blah[0]); // gives this... ["Species", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"]
```

I am able to change the name of the first key called `Species` here to `newthing` like this:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(blah).split('"Species":').join('"newthing":'));
```

But if I didn't know it was called 'Species', but knew it was the first element of 'mynames', I thought I could do the same thing like this:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(blah).split('mynames[0]:').join('"newthing":'));
```

or

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(blah).split('"mynames[0]":').join('"newthing":'));
```

but both fail.  Is there a way of doing this simply?

Comment: try `split('"' + mynames[0] + '":')`

Comment: @JaromandaX - of course, thanks.

Comment: Turning structured data into a string to do this is silly, especially if you don't know the range of values in the JSON.  What's to say a key's text might also exist in a value?  It might work depending on the data but I think it's kludgy and fragile.

Comment: Why not `.replace(mynames[0], "newthing")`?

Comment: @DanFarrell - thanks Dan, that's a very good point.  In the very specific circumstances I need this for, the data will always be strings for keys and numeric values for values.  However, I'd still rather use a more robust method.

Comment: FYI, this is an array of objects, not JSON. JSON is a textual, language-indepdent data format. You have JavaScript.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks Felix - good point.

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want is

```
blah[0].newthing = blah[0][mynames[0]];
delete blah[0][mynames[0]];
```

> but knew it was the first element of 'mynames',

Note that the order of keys is not guaranteed, so that might not work in every environment or even for multiple runs.

Answer (score 0):

[How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-to-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object) explains how the `delete` keyword can be used to remove properties.  You can simply set the new property to the value of the old, then delete the old.